# emacs major-mode font-lock between characters (parenthesis, quotes, etc)

Tags: emacs, syntax, lisp, syntax-highlighting, mode

I'm trying to setup an emacs major-mode which essentially just highlights text between lots of different characters, in different colors.  I have square brackets working with:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\[\\(.*\\)\\]"
                             1 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))
```

but when I try replacing the `[` and `]` with other characters, it stops working.  For example, round parentheses '`()`' does **not** work:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\(\\(.*\\)\\)"
                             1 font-lock-function-name-face prepend)))
```

Trying single, double, or back-quotes, etc also don't work.  I'm completely unfamiliar with lisp-syntax --- what am I doing wrong?  Also: is there any way to include the characters bracketing the expression?

Comment: Emacs has its own regex syntax. Literal parens for instance aren't escaped.
You can read more at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression

Comment: Thanks @abo-abo, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the documentation for emacs regexps; for example, why are two backslashes needed here: `\\[`?

Comment: Since it's a string, it's actually a single backslash.
Backslashes are escaped in strings to allow for e.g. `\n`.
So the regexp is `\[`. It means literal `[`, instead of one that starts a `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing regular expressions and regular strings.

Try these:

```el
;; square brackets - escape the first one so you don't get a [..] regexp
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\(\\[.*]\\)"
                         1 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))

;; parentheses - don't escape the parentheses you want to match!
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\((.*)\\)"
                         1 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))

;; quotes - single escape so you don't break your string:
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\(\".*\"\\)"
                         1 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))

;; other characters - not regexps, so don't escape them:
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\('.*'\\)"
                         1 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\(<.*>\\)"
                         1 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))
```